# working for US Comany In India

Tags: india, income

An employee of US Company posted at Bangalore.

The salary is credited by US company after Deduction of tax as per US laws then credited to the Bank  account in India.

Employee is resident because of residing in India more than 180 days.

How to claim credit of tax paid in foreign country when accounting periods are different? Where I have to disclose in the return(i.e.ITR 1) the taxes already deducted by US entity when I am going to file return in India?

Comment: Are you a US citizen? Why are you paying US taxes?

Comment: These two questions are so close, would you mind expanding the other to cover all of your questions?